# tensorflow-models/mobilenet not working when device offline

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I use tensorflow-models/mobilenet for application Reat native of me.
The application works well when there is a network. But when the device is offline, on IOS applications it does not load model.

```
 async function predictMobilenet() {
        try {
            setTextshow(' LOADING...')
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            console.log(' Load model...')
            //const tfReady = await tf.ready();
            const tfReady = await tf.ready();
            console.log('Uffect load model')
            const model = await mobilenet.load();
            const imgB64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(selectedImage.localUri, {
                encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
            });
            const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, 'base64').buffer;
            const raw = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer)
            const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(raw);
            const prediction = await model.classify(imageTensor);
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var time = end - start;
            setTextshow(JSON.stringify(prediction))
            setTime(time)
        }catch (e) {
            setTextshow(e.toString())
            console.log(e)
        }
    }



code line: const model = await mobilenet.load(); not working on ios when device offline
```

Error on iOS:

```
error : network request failed.
```

But on Android, my application works well.